# Why is the width of my CSS animation dependent on previous HTML or CSS features?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to have an underline that goes the width of each text. E.g. I have headers "Team" and "Schedule", and I want the underline to go the full length of each word despite them being different lengths. This is my current code (I've included most all of the code):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.change .menu {
  background-color: white;
  width: 60vh;
  height: 100vh;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -30px;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.change .content {
  position: relative;
}

.menu a {
  opacity: 0%;
}

.change .menu a {
  opacity: 100%;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: -50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  z-index: 2;
}

.content h3 {
  opacity: 0%;
}

.underbar {
  position: relative;
}

.underbar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  background: #24478f;
  transition: width .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s ease;
}

. .underbar:hover:after {
  width: 12%;
  left: 0;
  background: #24478f;
}

.sub_underbar {
  position: relative;
}

.sub_underbar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffcc00;
  transition: width .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s ease;
}

.sub_underbar:hover:after {
  width: 38% left: 0;
  background: #ffcc00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="team_sunset.JPG" alt="Team Picture" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered" style="font-size:20vw;">UMWSC</div>
  <div class="header" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
    <div class="menu" id="menu_scroll">
      <div class="content">
        <a href="main_page.html" class="underbar">HOME</a>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">MISSION STATEMENT</h3>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">CONTACT US</h3>
        <a href="team.html" class="underbar">TEAM</a>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">ROSTER</h3>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">LEADERSHIP</h3>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">SCHEDULE</h3>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">STATS</h3>
        <a href="news.html" class="underbar">NEWS</a>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">GALLERY</h3>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">BLOG</h3>
        <a href="get_involved.html" class="underbar">GET INVOLVED</a>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">MERCH</h3>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">DONATE</h3>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">PARTNER WITH US</h3>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">WORK WITH US</h3>
        <a href="more_info.html" class="underbar">MORE INFO</a>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">FORMS</h3>
        <h3 class="sub_underbar">FAQS</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="scroll_header">
      <h4>UMWSC</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think currently the width is dependent on some parent feature because when you hover to the right of the text, there's a specific spot that "triggers" the animation of the underline to occur.

I'm sure there's a lot wrong with my previous code that might be causing this current issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

EDIT: The picture shows how the underline goes past the width I want it to go, I just want it to be the length of the word 'HOME'. [drop-down content picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OQsT.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly you want the main menu titles underline to span across the biggest item in that group of items. If so try this:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}     
     
.menu {
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 2;
}

.change.menu {
    background-color: white;
    width: 60vh;
    height: 100vh;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -30px;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 8px;
    left: 16px;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
}

.change.content {
    position: relative;
}

.underbar {
    position: relative;
}

.underbar:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    background: #24478f;
    transition: width .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s ease;
}

.underbar:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #24478f;
}

.sub_underbar {
    position: relative;
}

.sub_underbar:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    right: 0;
    background: #ffcc00;
    transition: 100% .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 100% .5s ease;
}

.sub_underbar:hover:after {
    width: 38% left: 0;
    background: #ffcc00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <div class="menu" id="menu_scroll">
            <div class="content-holder">
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="main_page.html" class="underbar">HOME</a>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">MISSION STATEMENT</h3>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">CONTACT US</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="team.html" class="underbar">TEAM</a>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">ROSTER</h3>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">LEADERSHIP</h3>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">SCHEDULE</h3>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">STATS</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="news.html" class="underbar">NEWS</a>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">GALLERY</h3>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">BLOG</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="get_involved.html" class="underbar">GET INVOLVED</a>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">MERCH</h3> 
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">DONATE</h3>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">PARTNER WITH US</h3>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">WORK WITH US</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="more_info.html" class="underbar">MORE INFO</a>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">FORMS</h3>
                    <h3 class="sub_underbar">FAQS</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="scroll_header"> 
                <h4>UMWSC</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes! But is there a way to ensure the underline only goes the length of the text?

Comment: I updated my answer but I'm not sure if I am understanding your question maybe add another example

Comment: I think for some reason the underline is going to the full width of it's parent container (not sure exactly which is the parent) but I'll add a picture to show how far the underline is going. Instead of this happening, I just want the underline to go the width of 'HOME'. And the other sub categories in the drop-down content ('TEAM', 'ROSTER', etc.)